# I am not able to use the "apt update" command

Tags: apt, package-management, permissions, updates, dpkg

Whenever I use the command `sudo apt update` i get this:

```
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
E: Could not create temporary file for /var/lib/apt/extended_states - mkstemp (30: Read-only file system)
E: Failed to write temporary StateFile /var/lib/apt/extended_states
W: Could not open file '/var/log/apt/term.log' - OpenLog (30: Read-only file system)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - pkgDPkgPM::Go (30: Read-only file system)
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Please ensure that you have write permissions on your disk:  `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`, and then retry `sudo apt update`

Comment: What @CharlesGreen said should work as long as no other process is using it. If that does not work, trry restarting the computer

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` file and retry.

I had similar problem when my earlier installation had failed. Sometimes that file stays locked.